# UITableView, move first row to the last

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use the methed `moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:toPath`,but it is to fast,i want the first row slowly go down to the last,how can i do this

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve in any of following way-

1. using `NSTimer` to insert some delay
2. using `performSelector withDelay`.